# Почему после присваивания в ngOnInit значение undefined?

Tags: angular2, typescript, visual-studio-code

Есть метод:

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this._assemblyService.getAssemblies().subscribe(result => {
      this.assemblies = <Assembly[]>result;
      console.log(result);
      console.log(this.assemblies);
      this._paginator = new PaginatorLocal<Assembly>(this.assemblies, 1);
      for (let index = 1; index <= this._paginator.pageCount; index++) {
        this._pageArray.push(index);
      }
    }
    );
  }
```

После присваивания `this.assemblies` ее значение не меняется.

Скриншот, что бы показать это:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
сделал шаг:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как видно ничего не присвоилось. В консоле браузера никаких ошибок нету.

После того, как я прохожу ngOnInit, то значения появляются.

**UPD**

Оказывается если в анонимной функции прописать **_this.**, то тогда отображается значение в классовых полях.

Так и должно быть?

Comment: Это связано с потерей контекста. В ts Вы это не замечаете, но при компиляции в js это заметно. Под капотом компилятор делает, `_this = this`.

Comment: @KostiantynOkhotnyk т.е это нормально?

Comment: да. Кстати `_this = this` он НЕ сделает. Если Вы не вставите хотя бы одну операцию с `this`. Например `this._assemblyService.getAssemblies().subscribe(result => {debugger;})` если в subscribe вывести _this то он покажет undefined. Но если сделать так `this._assemblyService.getAssemblies().subscribe(result => {debugger; console.log(this.assemblies )})`, то _this уже будет ссылаться на текущий объект класса